# Query values from each json in a json array on postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Each record in my database has a json list, from which I'm trying to return a value inside each element.

I'm trying to return

```
environmental services, energy & utilities
```

From

```
[
  {
    "key": "environmental services"
  },
  {
    "key": "energy & utilities"
  }
]
```

And.

```
construction
```

From

```
[
  {
    "key": "construction"
  }
]
```

Where the length of each json list in each record is undetermined.

**I can get the first value with:**

```
select
  column_name -> 0 -> 'key'
from table
```

But how to get all.

How can I do this in postgresql?

Answer (score 1):

Use the function [`jsonb_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) in a lateral join to get all elements of the arrays and the aggregate function [`string_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html):

```
with my_table(json_col) as (
values
('[
  {
    "key": "environmental services"
  },
  {
    "key": "energy & utilities"
  }
]'::jsonb),
('[
  {
    "key": "construction"
  }
]')
)

select string_agg(value->>'key', ', ')
from my_table
cross join jsonb_array_elements(json_col)
group by json_col       -- use PK here (if exists)

                 string_agg                 
--------------------------------------------
 environmental services, energy & utilities
 construction
(2 rows)
```